# JavascriptInterface vs Phonegap. (Android web application)

Tags: javascript, android, performance, cordova, webview

## Phonegap or JavascriptInterface?

I am going to develop a android web-application, and was wondering if I should use PhoneGap, or a webview with JavascripInterface?

Is there any difference in performance between the two?

PS: I only need to use the gps function of the phone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think Phonegap sounds like the most suited as if you use the Cordova Command Line Interface, you shouldn't have to touch native code.

There is some info on setting up a new project here: http://www.gauntface.co.uk/blog/2013/07/18/cordova-web-best-practices/

Comment: But i don't mind touching native code... I'm more interested in performance.

Comment: In that case the javascript interface would be more light weight than cordova. The performance will then be easier for you to maintain / track over time. I dont think cordova is going to be inherently slow in comparison to js interace, but im not aware of any metrics for this.

Comment: okey, thanks! :)
Thanks for the help, but I'm not going to accept the answer in hope of getting more answers. Although that most likely wont happen :P